# proper FFT length for ARM CMSIS DSP fft function

Tags: arm, signal-processing, fft, digital, cmsis

I'm currently trying to use the ARM CMSIS DSP library on my cortex m3 PSoC 5lp chip.
I ran into some issues using some of the functions and I have a question about using the functions `arm_cfft_q15` (or any of the `arm_cfft_***` functions).

Say I have

```
    q15_t ADC_samples[1024];
    q15_t MAG_of_fft[1024];
```

and I run

```
    arm_cfft_q15(1024pt_fft, ADC_samples, sample_length);
```

this does the transforms 'in place'.  Now because of that, since the FFT returns both real and imaginary values, it will in fact only be able to return 
an fft of length 512 or is it 512 of the 1024 FFT samples?
After getting the FFT I do

```
    arm_cmplx_mag_q15(ADC_samples, MAG_of_fft, fftlength);
```

where `fftlength` is 1024.

This returns `MAG_of_fft` and when I plot it, it does indeed seem to be the shape that I am expecting to see but I do not know exactly how to interpret the results since I don't know how long my FFT is exactly.  I am telling it I am doing a 1024pt FFT but it seems to be only returning a 512pt FFT, or only half of the 1024pt FFT, one or the other.

So am I getting this right?  This means that the `ADC_samples` array must be twice as long as the data in it order for me to get a 1024 pt FFT? and then I can calculate the magnitude of the FFT using that 2048 array by telling it the length of the FFT is 1024?

Can someone explain to me how to properly interpret these functions and what length FFT I should expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `arm_cfft` family of functions operate on complex valued signals. In other word a 1024-point FFT performed with `arm_cfft_q15` requires 1024 complex input samples which are represented by 2048 `q15_t` values (interleaved real and imaginary parts, as described in the [CMSIS DSP Software Library documentation](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/dsp/html/group___complex_f_f_t.html#details)). Upon return the buffer contains 1024 complex values (2048 `q15_t` values) corresponding to the frequency domain representation of the complex input signal.

So adapting [this example](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/dsp/html/arm_fft_bin_example_f32_8c-example.html#a11) to your case, you would compute the FFT with:

```
q15_t ADC_samples[2048];
arm_cfft_q15(1024pt_fft, ADC_samples, 0, 1);
```

The subsequent call

```
q15_t MAG_of_fft[1024];
arm_cmplx_mag_q15(ADC_samples, MAG_of_fft, fftlength);
```

with `fftlength=1024` then reduces the 1024 complex values (2048 `q15_t` values) in `ADC_samples` to 1024 real magnitude values (1024 `q15_t` values), and stores the result in `MAG_of_fft`.

As as side note, if you are in fact dealing with real valued signals, then you *could* use the same functions and filling every second index (the imaginary parts) of the `ADC_samples` buffer with zeros (thus using an `ADC_samples` buffer that is twice as large as your actual number of real samples). Alternatively, you can use the more efficient `arm_rfft` family of functions (described in [this section of the documentation](http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/cmsis/dsp/html/group___fast.html)).

Comment: Note that I purposely avoided complexifying the answer by getting too much into `arm_rfft` which does not seem to be the object of your question (I could elaborate in a separate question if needed).

Comment: Ok, I think that clears up my confusion about the size of the array input into the function.  I will also look into the arm_rfft family, if I have any questions abuot that I wil lbe sure to ask them.  thank you.